# django user followers retrieval from database

Tags: python, django

I have an application with a user follower system which I have been able to achieve but I try to retrieve individual user followers and following but I could not get it. Below is my code

**View.py**

```
def following(request):
    query = Contact.objects.filter(request.user.following)
    context = {
        'query': query
        }
    template = 'following.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='rel_from_set')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='rel_to_set')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from,self.user_to)

User.add_to_class('following',models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact,related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

**Template**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<h2>following</h2>
<div id="action-list">

<h1>{{ results.get_full_name }}</h1>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Additional code would be added on request.

Comment: Please provide more code

Comment: what does the models look like?

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved two ways. First: your filter is not correct:

```
def following(request):
    query = Contact.objects.filter(user_from=request.user)
    context = {
        'query': query
        }
    template = 'following.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Another solution with the reverse relation using the `related_name`

```
def following(request):
    query = request.user.rel_from_set.all()
    context = {
        'query': query
        }
    template = 'following.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Works similar, of course, for the `user_to` field of `Contact`.

EDIT: Your template doesn't use the proper context variables you have defined in view `following`. So you'll need to tweak it a bit:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
<h2>following</h2>
<div id="action-list">

{% for result in query %}
    <h1>{{ result }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It doesn’t display the following or followers. Kindly help review

Comment: I think you have to better specify your question. Do you mean for example: `User.objects.filter(rel_from_set__user_to=request.user)`?

Comment: No. I adapted your solution but it doesn’t display the users that are following me or the users I am following when I change it to user_to

Comment: Alright, can you add the code of your template to the question as well?

Comment: I have added it